# Remove bean from spring util list

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, overriding, alias

I have a spring util list of beans. I want to remove one of them.

***Eg***-

```
<util:list id="abc" value-type="com.Sample">
        <ref bean="bean1"/>
        <ref bean="bean2"/>
        <ref bean="bean3"/>
        <ref bean="bean4"/>
        <ref bean="bean5"/>
        <ref bean="bean6"/>
        <ref bean="bean7"/>
    </util:list>
```

I want to override this list in such a way that it does not contain

> bean3

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing the bean did the trick. Although, I believe there must be an elegant solution.

```
<util:list id="abc" value-type="com.Sample">
        <ref bean="bean1"/>
        <ref bean="bean2"/>
        <!--<ref bean="bean3"/>-->
        <ref bean="bean4"/>
        <ref bean="bean5"/>
        <ref bean="bean6"/>
        <ref bean="bean7"/>
    </util:list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds as though you want to conditionally add the bean. Programmatically for could use

```
@Bean(name="abc")
public List<Sample> sampleList(){
    List<Sample> sampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (condition) {
      sampleList.add(bean3);
    }
    // add other beans
    return sampleList;
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a more spring.xml based solution.

Comment: In that case [Spring profiles](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml) is probably what you want