# How to disable OOTB entryMergeFilterConfigurableProduct in custom extension?

Tags: xml, spring, configuration, cart, sap-commerce-cloud

I wanted to disable one of the entry filters(entryMergeFilterConfigurableProduct) provided by Hybris OOTB. Because of this filter, some cart entries are getting merged, though it is not supposed to as per our business logic.

I would like to override the definition in my custom extension. But it is not working as expected.

OOTB xml code:

```
    <alias name="defaultEntryMergeStrategy" alias="entryMergeStrategy"/>
        <bean id="defaultEntryMergeStrategy" class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.strategies.impl.DefaultEntryMergeStrategy">
        <property name="entryMergeFilters" ref="commerceCartEntryMergeFilters"/>
    </bean>


<bean id="entryMergeFilterConfigurableProduct" class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.impl.EntryMergeFilterConfigurableProduct">
        <property name="productConfigurableChecker" ref="productConfigurableChecker" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entryMergeFilterIsEntryUpdatable" class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.impl.EntryMergeFilterIsEntryUpdatable">
        <property name="entryOrderChecker" ref="commerceOrderEntryModifiableChecker" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entryMergeFilterPointOfService" class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.impl.EntryMergeFilterPointOfService"/>

    <bean id="entryMergeFilterGiveAway" class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.impl.EntryMergeFilterGiveAway"/>

    <bean id="entryMergeFilterProduct" class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.impl.EntryMergeFilterProduct"/>

    <bean id="entryMergeFilterUnits" class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.impl.EntryMergeFilterUnits"/>

    <bean id="entryMergeFilterEntryGroup" class="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.impl.EntryMergeFilterEntryGroup"/>

    <util:list id="commerceCartEntryMergeFilters" value-type="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.EntryMergeFilter">
        <ref bean="entryMergeFilterEntryGroup"/>
        <ref bean="entryMergeFilterGiveAway"/>
        <ref bean="entryMergeFilterProduct"/>
        <ref bean="entryMergeFilterUnits"/>
        <ref bean="entryMergeFilterPointOfService"/>
        <ref bean="entryMergeFilterConfigurableProduct"/>
        <ref bean="entryMergeFilterIsEntryUpdatable"/>
    </util:list>
```

Can you please let me know what needs to be changed to disable particular filter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove bean from spring util list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679385/remove-bean-from-spring-util-list)

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, ListMegreDerective might be helpful but a remove capability has not been introduced yet. This is available only for the populators list.
https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/1905/en-US/515ccff5d01b427f851694fb8ec989e6.html

A usual solution is to override the bean e.g entryMergeFilterProduct or define the new bean for filters without the particular filter and make an alias.

```
<alias name="customizedYourAssignedCartEntryMergeFilters" alias="commerceCartEntryMergeFilters"/>


<util:list id="customizedYourAssignedCartEntryMergeFilters" value-type="de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.EntryMergeFilter">
    <ref bean="entryMergeFilterEntryGroup"/>
    <!-Your list of the Filters-->
</util:list>
```

Comment: Welcome and thank you for contributing. If possible, please try to avoid posting links in answers. They may end up broken or pointing to something different in the future.